# When applying a stencil to a cylindric object, is there a way to make it wrap around from top to bottom?

Tags: texturing, uv

I am very new to Blender, and have been using it to apply stencils to 3D aircraft models so I can generate 2D textures for flight simulator. In the picture below, I have scaled my stencil to the desired size and position of the fuselage, and began painting it on. However, I am finding that the stencil does not "wrap" to the bottom of the fuselage (I would ideally like the red box filled in). I know this is definitely the intended behavior of Blender, so I'm wondering what the correct technique is to get my stencil to meet at the top and bottom of the fuselage. Sorry if my nomenclature is wrong or confusing here, as I said, I'm completely new to Blender. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The red box is on your image/UV.  Is there actual mesh that corresponds with that area of the mesh, or is it also a hole in the UV?  If there is no actual mesh, then you just need to increase your texture paint's "bleed" distance-- but there's no reason to care about it, unless you're viewing your model at such a distance that the textures are all a muddy mess anyways.  If there is mesh there, that you want colored, you can change texture paint to not falloff with normal, and disable occlusion + culling-- or, there are plenty of techniques that do not require texture paint at all.

Answer (score 3):

In your material shader nodes are you using a Texture Coordinate node's UV output?

[image]

Try using the Object or Generated output.  Or....

As evidenced by the gaps for the doors(?) of the fuselage, there isn't any UV mapping defined at those locations.  Check the Object Data Properties >> UV Maps, and look in the UV Editor.   If you see that there are what appear to be these gaps (like the bottom and hatch-ways),

[image]

then you can correct this to include more.  In the 3D Viewport, with your object (plane) in Edit mode, select the vertices to want to add (or 'a' to select-all), and you'll see a rather messed up looking UV Map that needs to be cleaned up:

[image]

Re-do the UVMap with the UV Editor menu UV >> Unwrap >> Smart UV Project (project as in projection).  This gives you a new, coherent UV Map that will include areas where you want your image material to be included.

[image]